# Unable to display all locations in the same view in V2 GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to display all marked locations (kind of a world view) in the same view. But the view does not include all of them . I have gone through most of the posts  related to this and all of them have the same below solution

```
   if (mapView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
        mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") // We use the new method when supported
            @SuppressLint("NewApi") // We check which build version we are using.
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                 LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                 builder.include(new LatLng(0,0));
                 builder.include(new LatLng(-30.54,43.34));
                 builder.include(new LatLng(40.54,98.34));
                 builder.include(new LatLng(-14.235004, -51.92528));
                 builder.include(new LatLng(-27.47093, 153.0235));
                 builder.include(new LatLng(35.4112, 135.8337));

                 CameraUpdate center=
                            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(),0);


                        mMap.moveCamera(center);


            }

        });}
            }
```

This does not work . It just shows few of the locations. For eg the last Lat Long is that of Japan but that is not displayed in the View

Please help me . What am i doing wrong here ? Please please i am really stuck since days now.

Ram

Yes,

This is V2 on Android I am using

```
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate; 
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory; 
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment; 
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition; 
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng; 
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBound
```

Comment: What API is this? Is this on android?

Comment: Yes, This is V2 on Android  I am using                           import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to show almost the whole world. This is currently not possible because of a min zoom level limitation, which is 2 on small phones, but can be higher on different devices.

See the [`getMaxZoomLevel` and `getMinZoomLevel`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#getMaxZoomLevel%28%29).

Comment: So does that mean that there is no way to show the world map from  Google Maps in an android application ? I find it really surprising that google hasnt provided that functionality . All i am looking for is to show the world map the moment the app is loaded . Is there no other way ?

Comment: @ramdalal Yes, there is no way. I think having 256x256 dp map (zoom level 0) is blocked by [this gmaps api issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5285). You may want to post a feature request for having the ability to zoom out to level 0. I'll support it.

Comment: Ok, i will definitely post a feature request and let you know. Thanks again for the support and help.

Comment: Hi MaciejGorski , the issue id raised with Google is 5724